# Increase performance of df.rolling(...).apply(...) for large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dask, swifter

Execution time of this code is too long.

```
df.rolling(window=255).apply(myFunc)
```

My dataframes shape is (500, 10000).

```
                   0         1 ... 9999
2021-11-01  0.011111  0.054242 
2021-11-04  0.025244  0.003653 
2021-11-05  0.524521  0.099521 
2021-11-06  0.054241  0.138321 
...
```

I make the calculation for each date with the last 255 date values. myFunc looks like:

```
def myFunc(x):
   coefs = ...
   return np.sqrt(np.sum(x ** 2 * coefs))
```

I tried to use swifter but performances are the same :

```
import swifter
df.swifter.rolling(window=255).apply(myFunc)
```

I also tried with Dask, but I think I didn't understand it well because the performance are not much better:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df)
ddf = ddf.rolling(window=255).apply(myFunc, raw=False)
ddf.execute()
```

I didn't manage to parallelize the execution with partitions. How can I use dask to improve performance ? I'm on Windows.

Comment: We need a piece of dataframe, a function `myFunc` and the result you want to achieve. And so the question is too general.

Comment: the question is a little bit too broad but if you use linux you can try pandarallel and the parallel_apply function. it uses all cores that you have available but it's a little buggy on windows.

Comment: I updated my question. I'm on Windows

Comment: dask.dataframe partitions rowwise. you're doing a rolling operation (so cross-row communication is needed), broadcast across a huge number of columns. This is just the opposite setup to how dask is structured. To use dask in this context, I would manually segment your dataframe into many dataframes in groups of columns, then map the operation across the dataframe. you could use `dask.distributed`'s `client.map` using a threaded scheduler to share the dataframe in memory. if you put together a real [mre] then we could set this up.

Comment: you could also just do this with numpy or `numba`. seems to be a very straightforward operation along a single axis of a large homogenous array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you are using `numpy` functions, specify the parameter `raw=True`. Toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    coefs = 2
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(x ** 2 * coefs))    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((500, 10000)))

%%time
res = df.rolling(250).apply(foo)

Wall time: 359.3 s

# with raw=True
%%time
res = df.rolling(250).apply(foo, raw=True)

Wall time: 15.2 s
```

You can also easily parallelize your calculations using the [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library. Only two additional lines of code!

```py
# pip install parallel-pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

#initialize parallel-pandas
ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=8, disable_pr_bar=True)

def foo(x):
    coefs = 2
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(x ** 2 * coefs))    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((500, 1000)))

# p_apply - is parallel analogue of apply method
%%time
res = df.rolling(250).p_apply(foo, raw=True, executor='processes')

Wall time: 2.2 s
```

With `engine='numba'`

```py
%%time
res = df.rolling(250).p_apply(foo, raw=True, executor='processes', engine='numba')

Wall time: 1.2 s
```

Total speedup is `359/1.2 ~ 300`!

Comment: Note that the df in the OP’s question has 10 times as many rows, so the timing should be about 10x this for the full problem.

Comment: The dependence is non-linear. I fixed dataframe size.

Comment: Oops sorry I mean 10x the columns. It won’t be exactly linear but it will not be a trivial increase I think

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `numpy`+[`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) pretty efficiently.

Quick MRE:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, numba

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(500, 10000)),
    index=pd.date_range("2021-11-01", freq="D", periods=500)
)

coefs = np.random.random(size=255)
```

Write the function using pure numpy operations and simple loops, making use of [`numba.njit(parallel=True)`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html#compilation-options) and [`numba.prange`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops):

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_func(values, coefficients):
    # define result array: size of original, minus length of
    # coefficients, + 1
    result_tmp = np.zeros(
        shape=(values.shape[0] - len(coefficients) + 1, values.shape[1]),
        dtype=values.dtype,
    )

    result_final = np.empty_like(result_tmp)

    # nested for loops are your friend with numba!
    # (you must unlearn what you have learned)
    for j in numba.prange(values.shape[1]):
        for i in range(values.shape[0] - len(coefficients) + 1):
            for k in range(len(coefficients)):
                result_tmp[i, j] += values[i + k, j] ** 2 * coefficients[k]

        result_final[:, j] = np.sqrt(result_tmp[:, j])

    return result_final
```

This runs very quickly:

```py
In [5]: %%time
   ...: result = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     numba_func(df.values, coefs),
   ...:     index=df.index[len(coefs) - 1:],
   ...: )
   ...:
   ...:
CPU times: user 1.69 s, sys: 40.9 ms, total: 1.73 s
Wall time: 844 ms
```

Note: I'm a huge fan of dask. But the first rule of dask performance is [don't use dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html). If it's small enough to fit comfortably into memory, you'll usually get the best performance from tuning your pandas or numpy operations and leveraging speedups from cython, numba, etc. And once a problem is big enough to move to dask, these same tuning rules apply to the operations you perform on dask chunks/partitions, too!